# Object not found error on OK button in the dialog box

Tags: java, testing, rft

In my application , by clicking the save button, the dialog prompts a message with OK button. While recording 'the OK button' got recorded and shows 'text_ok().click(atpoint(11,8));'. But during play back it shows me a  'Object not found' error.
Recently updated the RFT Version 8.2.2.1 after this only this issue is seen.
Can anyone say me how to solve this problem or any coding in java.

My regression is waiting due to this, your help is highly appreciable.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned what type of dialog window it is. But you can try the IWindow API of RFT to find active top window and perform the click as specifed below.
The Following  code for eg can handle an alert dialog box in html by  calling

```
  handleDialogButton("Message from Webpage", "ok");
```

Or,to click on canel button on Notepad's Font dialog (Format>Font) by calling

```
      handleDialogButton("font","cancel");
```

-------Sample code----

```
/*
 * Activates the top window with the given caption and clicks on the child control(window) with the specified text
 * @param caption- Caption of the Dialog window
 * @param btnToClick- Text of the button(any other control) to click 
 */
void handleDialogButton(String caption,String btnToClick)
{
    IWindow[] windows = getTopWindows();
    for(IWindow window: windows)
    {           
        if(window.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(caption))
        {       
            window.activate();
            //window.close(); //we can just close it also n break.              
   IWindow[] children = window.getChildren(); // OR go thru the children to get the child 
            for(IWindow child:children)
            {               
                if(child.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(btnToClick))
                {
                    child.click();                      
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
    unregisterAll();
}
```

Comment: Its a Web Page dialog issues. Its a Aspx

Answer (score -1):

From the poing of Selenium Web driver API  i recommend you do the following:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
   alert.accept();
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: Downvoted because the question is about Rational Functional Tester and not Selenium